# Wikidata content negotiation

Tags: rdf, wikidata, content-negotiation

I was wondering why Wikidata content negotiation results with more than one entities in the file. For instance P2044 in the browser

`http://www.wikidata.org/entity/P2044.nt`

gives me triples also about Q6452016 entity:

```
http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q6452016
```

I would expect either triples about P2044 or document metadata.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, Q6452016 is a "subject item" for P2044, i. e. they are closely related... Cf. https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T85753 though...

Comment: Thank you @StanislavKralin for pointing out subject item property..but I don't see why it should be included in the content negotiation anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many options of what to produce in an RDF output (as well as there is no [standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#describe) on what to return in a `DESCRIBE` query result).

In Wikidata, you can use one of [these](https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/plugins/gitiles/mediawiki/extensions/Wikibase/+/master/repo/includes/LinkedData/EntityDataSerializationService.php#317) options documented [here](https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/plugins/gitiles/mediawiki/extensions/Wikibase/+/master/repo/includes/Rdf/RdfProducer.php#11).  See also [RDF Dump Format](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format) about the Wikidata data model.

Perhaps http://www.wikidata.org/entity/P2044.ttl?flavor=dump is what you need. By default, `flavor` is `full`.

---

As for `wd:Q6452016`, it is a "subject item" (`wdt:P1629`) for `wd:P2044`, i. e. a very closely related entity. People even [propose](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T85753) to use labels of subject items as fallbacks for missing labels of properties.