# Constructing all Wikidata triples in SPARQL that have to do with a certain identifier

Tags: sparql, uniqueidentifier, triples, wikidata-query-service

I am trying to return a list of triples by using a construct query in the Wikidata SPARQL query service. 
I want all triples of people who have a GTAA_ID identifier. In addition to this,  of all people who have a GTAA_ID, I want all triples containing the person with a GTAA_ID as the subject + all combinations of predicates and objects.

Take the following example:
Tom Hanks has a GTAA_ID (identifier). Tom Hanks also has a lot of other statements and identifiers in Wikidata. I want to retrieve everything that has to do with Tom Hanks (as he has a GTAA_ID).

So for example:

```
Tom Hanks | GTAA_ID    | 106942
Tom Hanks | residence  | Los Angeles
Tom Hanks | residence  | Oakland
Tom Hanks | occupation | film actor
Tom Hanks | occupation | film director
```

and so on..

The example query Wikidata give (for all triples to do with Asthma) is:

```
#CONSTRUCT query to get the RDF graph for a Wikidata item (e.g. asthma)
CONSTRUCT {
  wd:Q35869 ?p ?o .
  ?o ?qualifier ?f .
  ?o prov:wasDerivedFrom ?u .
  ?u ?a ?b .
}
WHERE {
  wd:Q35869 ?p ?o .
  OPTIONAL {?o ?qualifier ?f .}
  OPTIONAL {?o prov:wasDerivedFrom ?u .
  ?u ?a ?b .}
}
```

This returns a list of triples that has to do with the item 'Asthma'.
However, what I want to do is return a list of triples where the item is a person with a GTAA_ID.

This is the code which returns all subjects with the corresponding GTAA_ID:

```
CONSTRUCT {
  ?s ps:1741 ?o .
  }
WHERE {
  ?s ps:P1741 ?o.
  }
```

and the link to the [Wikidata SPARQL Query Service](https://query.wikidata.org/)

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: "All" is much more than you probably think: see e.g. https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Special:EntityData/Q2263.ttl?flavor=full

Comment: In [`DESCRIBE`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#identifyingResources) queries, more than one variable can be given. Wikidata data model is [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format).

Comment: Thus, I'd suggest you to get list of people with GTAA ID's and then use curl. In addition to `full`, there are `dump`, `long` and `simple`, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48391157/7879193