# OPTIONAL not working with SPARQL query on local YASGUI editor

Tags: group-by, sparql, group-concat, wikidata-query-service, cliopatria

I am once again having trouble with SPARQL. 
First off, a bit of background information:
I have been using the [Wikidata Query Service](https://query.wikidata.org/) to retrieve data from Wikidata.
As the Wikidata SPARQL endpoint is limited and timeouts occur for large tasks, I figured I would:

1. Split the queries into several smaller ones
2. Download them as .csv
3. Convert them to .nt N-Triples
4. Import them into Cliopatra (which uses SWI-Prolog)
5. Use the built-in YASGUI SPARQL Editor to query the data locally

As of now, the query works in the Wikidata Query Service. 
However, locally I am not getting the OPTIONAL function to work.

My Wikidata code is [as follows](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fq%20%3FGTAA_ID%20%3Fpseudonym%20%3Fdate_of_death%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%28group_concat%28DISTINCT%20%3FoccupationLabel%3Bseparator%3D%22%2C%20%22%29%20as%20%3FOccupations%20%29%0AWHERE%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fq%20wdt%3AP1741%20%3FGTAA_ID.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%3Fq%20wdt%3AP742%20%3Fpseudonym.%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%3Fq%20wdt%3AP570%20%3Fdate_of_death.%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%3Fq%20wdt%3AP106%20%3Foccupation.%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22nl%22.%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Foccupation%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FoccupationLabel.%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0AGROUP%20BY%20%3Fq%20%3FGTAA_ID%20%3Fpseudonym%20%3Fdate_of_death) (this is a smaller selection of all data I want to retrieve):

```
SELECT ?q ?GTAA_ID ?pseudonym ?date_of_death 
       (group_concat(DISTINCT ?occupationLabel;separator=", ") as ?Occupations )
WHERE{
      ?q wdt:P1741 ?GTAA_ID.
      OPTIONAL {?q wdt:P742 ?pseudonym.}
      OPTIONAL {?q wdt:P570 ?date_of_death.}
      OPTIONAL {?q wdt:P106 ?occupation.}
      SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "nl". 
                            ?occupation rdfs:label ?occupationLabel.}
      }
GROUP BY ?q ?GTAA_ID ?pseudonym ?date_of_death
```

and this correctly retrieves:

```
q        | GTAA_ID  | pseudonym | date_of_death | occupation
Q3295087 | 102376   |           | 2000-11-05    | acteur
Q2800419 | 89301    |           |               | politicus, staatsman
and so on
```

The point here being that it allows me to select all results that have a Wikidata ID and a GTAA ID and corresponding pseudonym, date_of_death and occupations (if available). Furthermore, if a person has multiple occupations, it separates them by a ',' and places them in the same row.

However, as stated above I downloaded the files to be able to query them locally. To do this I converted the .csv files to .nt with the following format:

```
<?s> <?p> "?o"
```

where the object is a string.
Note that in the following examples, the ?p is correctly used in the way I converted to .nt. (Therefore the PREFIX ps is used)
Loaded them into Cliopatria and used the following code in the YASGUI editor:

```
PREFIX ps: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/statement/>

SELECT ?q ?GTAA_ID ?date_of_death ?pseudonym 
       (group_concat(DISTINCT ?occupation;separator=", ") as ?occupations )

WHERE{
  ?q ps:P1741 ?GTAA_ID.
  OPTIONAL{?q ps:P742 ?pseudonym.}
  OPTIONAL{?q ps:P106 ?occupation.}
  OPTIONAL{?q ps:P570 ?date_of_death.}
     } 
GROUP BY ?q ?GTAA_ID ?date_of_death ?pseudonym
```

However, in this query, ?pseudonym ?occupation and ?date_of_death are optional, but the occupations are not concatenated into a single row.
[Query 1](https://gyazo.com/6f7275a616bec0f9befdb6da31a039e1)

If I replace the GROUP BY function with

```
GROUP BY ?q ?GTAA_ID
```

it does not display ?pseudonym and ?date_of_death at all, but does concatenate ?occupation. 
[Query 2](https://gyazo.com/5716330ce2c0d666433a20aaea62f428)

If I replace the GROUP BY function with

```
GROUP BY ?q ?GTAA_ID ?date_of_death
```

it concatenates only the ?occupation for a ?q that has a ?date_of_death. 
Those without a ?date_of_death are not concatenated into 1 row. Furthermore, it does not display any ?pseudonym at all.
[Query 3](https://gyazo.com/77a36ab78aa0a9b494cb2101905b38a2)

I suspect is has to do with the GROUP BY function in combination with the group_concat function. However, I do not understand why it works in the Wikidata Query Service but not on my localhost.
The locally used .nt file can be accessed [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13YBDIC34rxx4NUDqAa3JqUm6J1_MVBX3/view?usp=sharing)

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Resource"` in your .nt file? P.S. This was original question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49259737

Comment: `<http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q991> <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/statement/P742> Друг Кузьмы Пруткова ,` etc.

Comment: Unfortunately I have seem to made a mistake when converting to .nt
When querying wikidata, it displays the corresponding property as a string. 
The <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Resource" 
just describes the type of the property/object (last column) as a resource (which is displayed as a string).
However, for the purpose of my query, I think the whole #type and #resource section can be left out. Basically the .nt file should end at 
 line 93754.

Comment: Then upload correct file (validate file before uploading) Anyway, why do you think that the problem is related YASGUI? YASGUI just displays results. Do SPARQL results in CSV/XML/JSON satisfy you?

Comment: What does your SPARQL query give when you use YASGUI to run the query directly on Wikidata endpoint?

Comment: That's not a YASGUI issue, just his data...

Comment: I'm wondering why you didn't use SPARQL CONSTRUCT to directly get RDF triples back? This would avoid the conversion from CSV to RDF data. Just my two cents ...

Comment: I have updated the .nt file. I am not necessarily saying the issue is related to YASGUI, I just don't understand why my query does work with wikidata query service, but does not work in YASGUI when my local (sub)set corresponds with wikidata data. 
I also had a period where I was trying to get the relevant data with CONSTRUCT and also DESCRIBE, however my SPARQL expertise is not great and I was not able to retrieve only the relevant data.
I am also not able to run the query directly on Wikidata endpoint in YASGUI.

Comment: Furthermore, a reason why I am using .csv is because Wikidata allows me to download the file in either JSON, TSV or CSV.
The program I am using, Cliopatria, states that it accepts XML/RDF and Turtle. However, it does not seem to accept JSON. 
Furthermore, when Cliopatria displays results, it only allows me to download them as .csv . This is not an issue for me though, as I will be using the results in Excel.

Comment: I have successfully load your dump into Jena Fuseki. First query works fine, perhaps Cliopatria doesn't understand `group_concat` (possibly only with `separator`). In your second query non-grouping variable is used in the projection, try something like `select (sample(?date_of_death) as ?death)` (or use `max`, if Cliopatria doesn't understand `sample`).

Comment: @John What I wanted to say is that you can also download RDF e.g. as N-Triples - you only have to use SPARQL `CONSTRUCT` instead of `SELECT` Clearly, Cliopatria doesn't support JSON, that'S not an RDF format, thus, you should running SPARQL on it work?

Comment: In addition to @AKSW's advice: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49350592/7879193. Anyway, the whole data about entities with GTAA_ID is very large, see comments to your initial question.